# Modifying functional python compose() to return list of all intermediate values

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

In Python 3, here is my compose function one-liner, which I am trying to modify:

```py
def compose(*fncs):
  return functools.reduce(lambda f,g: lambda x: f(g(x)), fncs, lambda x: x)
```

When I compose a function with `c = compose(h, g, f)`, calling `c(x)` is equivalent to calling `h(g(f(x))`

By changing my existing one-liner as little as possible, I would like to create a `compose_intermed(*fncs)` function which returns a   slightly different kind of composed function.  This function, when called, returns not the final value of the composed functions, but a list whose first element is the final value, followed by all the intermediate values at each step in which composed functions are applied.

**When I compose a function with `ci = compose_intermed(h, g, f)`, calling `ci(x)` would return the list `[h(g(f(x))), g(f(x)), f(x)]`.**

I would like to modify the compose function *as little as possible*, continuing to use either `reduce` or perhaps a list comprehension, rather than loops.  I know there may be *easier* ways to do this, but I'm trying to use this as an exercise to improve my general understanding of the nexus of functional programming and Python 3.

**Bonus question:** Does this function have another more standardized name in the functional programming world?  I've searched several libraries, and I haven't yet found a library function for what I am trying to do.

Comment: See if you can figure out how to implement `scan`, which is like `reduce` but produces a list of accumulator values. I’d recommend implementing this in reverse, too (`pipeline(f, g, h)`, corresponding `pipeline_intermed`) and using `reversed` at the end.

Comment: @Ry- in python this is in `itertools.accumulate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ry's comment is a good starting point. In this post, I'll try to demonstrate what he/she is talking about -

```
from functools import reduce

def identity(x):
  return x

def pipeline(f = identity, *fs):
  return reduce(lambda r,f: lambda x: f(r(x)), fs, f)
```

Make two simple functions and test it out. Notice how `pipeline` applies the functions in left-to-right order -

```
def add1(x):
  return x + 1

def mult2(x):
  return x * 2

f = pipeline(mult2, add1, add1, add1)

print(f(10))
# 23
```

Next, implement `pipeline_intermediate`. Just as Ry comments, the output is reversed at the end using `[::-1]` -

```
def pipeline_intermediate(f = identity, *fs):
  return lambda x: reduce(lambda r,f: [f(r[0])]+r, fs, [f(x)]) [::-1]

g = pipeline_intermediate(mult2, add1, add1, add1)

print(g(10))

# [20, 21, 22, 23]
```

Now can you see how to implement right-to-left `compose_intermediate`? Can you see why it's more challenging?

Comment: The original `compose` function uses its accumulator to compose the function object in advance -- before it is ever called on actual data.  The `pipeline_intermediate` doesn't really reduce anything until called on actual data, right?  Any disadvantage to this?  I had sort of envisioned that the solution would combine the functions upfront, possibly decorating them (or something?) to return that additional intermediate value, but I wasn't exactly sure how to structure it.  What you've proposed may be the best or most generally accepted or perhaps the ONLY way to do this.  Any other thoughts?